# Bash complete not funcitoning as expected, capturing first result in COMPREPLY and then running all results as a command?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

This is a bit of a tricky one, let me setup up what I'm doing here first to give you an idea of what I'm trying to accomplish.

I'm reading from a set of ssh config files to get hosts and hostnames from these files. I'm doing this to run a custom script against specific hosts and to accomplish this I wanted to try out writing a script that supports bash complete with the hosts.

I'm ingesting the configs and parsing out the hosts and hostnames with awk, listing them in a dictionary and then using the keys from this dictionary to use with complete.

```
#!/bin/bash

NETWORKS_PATH=~/.ssh/Networks/
files=($(ls $NETWORKS_PATH))

declare -A a_dict

_read_network ()
{
    file=$1

    while read -r line; do    
        host=$(awk $line '$1 == "Host" { print $2 }')
    done < $file

    for hostiter in ${host[@]}; do
        hostname=$(ssh -n -tt -G $hostiter | awk '$1 == "hostname" { print $2 }') 

        a_dict[$hostiter]=$hostname
    done
}

_ff_completions()
{
    local hosts

    for file in ${files[@]}; do
        _read_network "$NETWORKS_PATH$file"
    done

    for key in "${!a_dict[@]}"; do
        hosts+="$key "
    done

    COMPREPLY=$(compgen -W "$hosts" -- "${COMP_WORDS[1]}")
}

complete -F _ff_completions ff
```

The hostnames and hosts are captured correctly and I'm able to output them as part of complete but complete appears to "inject" the first listed server as its first suggestion and gets stuck on it? If I try to run the command it passes all of the suggestions as commands. I'm a bit stumped, I'm not new to this just a bit out of practice.

[image: Server names outputting and being run as commands.]

Comment: Oh and I have to backspace through all of the suggestions like its being printed to the cli instead of like I would expect in something like ls.